# I have a problem using spatie/browsershot on Laravel

Tags: laravel

When I call this function:

```php
public  function  screenshot()
{
    $url = url("/google_search/11");

    $pathToImage = public_path("/__Uploads/__Screenshot/") . "screenshot.png";

    Browsershot::url($url)->save($pathToImage);
}
```

There is an error like below :

> Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException
> The command "PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin NODE_PATH=`npm root -g` node '/home/mazdsi/domains/mazdsi.com/public_html/screenshot/vendor/spatie/browsershot/src/../bin/browser.js' '{"url":"https://screenshot.mazdsi.com/google_search/11","action":"screenshot","options":{"type":"png","path":"/home/mazdsi/domains/mazdsi.com/public_html/screenshot/public/__Uploads/__Screenshot/screenshot.png","args":[],"viewport":{"width":800,"height":600}}}'" failed. Exit Code: 8(Unknown error) Working directory: /home/mazdsi/domains/mazdsi.com/public_html/screenshot/public Output: ================ Error Output: ================ /home/mazdsi/domains/mazdsi.com/public_html/screenshot/vendor/spatie/browsershot/bin/browser.js:5 const [, , ...args] = process.argv; ^ SyntaxError: Unexpected token [ at Module._compile (module.js:439:25) at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10) at Module.load (module.js:356:32) at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12) at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10) at startup (node.js:119:16) at node.js:945:3

How can I proceed?

Comment: Welcome to SO ... may be somthing wrong with node path `$PATH:/usr/local/bin NODE_PATH` in this you can check your node path by `which node` then you can use that

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```php
public  function  screenshot()
{
    $url = url("/google_search/11");

    $pathToImage = public_path("/__Uploads/__Screenshot/") . "screenshot.png";

    Browsershot::url($url)->save($pathToImage)->setNodeBinary('/usr/bin/node')->setNpmBinary('/usr/bin/npm');
}
```

becouse new version of Linux store node in `/usr/bin/node` and this library try to find this on `/usr/local/bin`

you can verify your path by `which node` cmd and `which npm`

> **NOTE**  This code may not work if you not give correct path

Comment: When i run which node result is /usr/bin/node and which npm result is /usr/bin/npm And I have substituted these two results in your suggested command. But still get the same error.

Comment: in my answer `npm` path was wrong i fixed it you can check now